# How much working is overworking Quikrete Concrete Mix

Tags: concrete

I mixed 92 pounds of mix by hand with shovel and trowel in a big plastic tub. Total added water was 4.5 quarts.

Hand mixing is slow. I didn't time it, but let's say it took 30 minutes total to mix and then weight out two buckets of 45 pounds of wet concrete each.

Then I poured it into two 16 inch diameter circle molds. (I'm making DIY weight lifting plates.) I tamped down the mix to level it with a wood block and tapped the mold sides.

There was a small amount of water bleed on top and bottom edge of molds which were not attached to  a plastic sheet underneath. I sponged off the bleed water with a paper towel just one time a few minutes after leveling the mix in the mold. Then I covered it with a plastic sheet.

The concrete to water ratio seemed good. I didn't go over the recommended max, not much bleed, the mix leveled off with a smooth top. Actually, I improvised a 12 inch slump cone while mixing, and that seemed good. It held up with only an inch or two of slump.

I figure I spent about one hour, no more that 90 minutes, starting the mixing to finally leaving the mix in the molds to set. Would that amount of time be considered overworking? At what point in time toward setting will mixing the concrete again ruin its strength.

Part of the reason for my concern is I used left over mix to make a 1.5 x 7 inch disk using a metal can with the top and bottom cut out. The day after all these molds set I removed the 7 inch mold first as a test. The concrete stuck to the metal mold, which I had oiled, so I tried tapping it out with a mallet. I got it out without breaking, but later while holding it in my hand, it just broken in half from its own weight. It had been setting for 12 hours.

I removed the 16 inch molds with no trouble at all, but waited a full 24 hours of setting time before pulling the molds. Both 16 inch plates are now pond curing in a tub of water.

I'm not sure if I did a bad mixing job or just treated my 7 inch mold too roughly while it was still soft and uncured.

Comment: Concrete reaches full strength after 28 days so taking it out of the mold after 12 hours was likely your downfall.

Comment: Maybe, but 28 days to full cure isn't the same as time to remove molds. My real concern is the 16" pieces which haven't had any rough handling out of their molds. Should I expect them to reach full strength?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, that's an [overly specific rule](https://precast.org/2013/10/28-day-myth) of thumb that's not particularly useful. It's also wrong 99% of the time. I'm not saying that your general point is wrong, but....

Comment: Was the "leftover mix" wet or dry prior to adding water? How long the leftover mix was left there and with or without protection?

Comment: @r13 the leftover mix was from the same hand mix I described. So, it was wet, but after doing the 16" molds, it might have been 2 hours old. I did not add more water. It was still workable. It wasn't protected, if I understand correctly. I was just sitting in the mixing bin. Maybe a half gallon leftover.

Comment: I think you have waited too long to use the mix. The fresh concrete has to be used ASAP, as the initial setting will start after about 30 minutes. During that span (30min - 2hrs),  the mix has already lost a lot of plasticity and bonding strength. Thus, it is almost like placing wet sand mix without enough bonding agent (cement), which is required to jell the concrete mix, and that's why it crumbles. You can lengthen the curing period to gain some strength, but will never reach the proposed strength.

Comment: @r13 If I follow what you've said, I think the 16" molds were finished just in time. For those two the mix, pouring, and final leveling took around 30 minutes. I didn't time it, but I was trying to work quickly. The 7" mold was the late pour. Really an after thought for using the few pounds of left over mix.

Comment: I was pointing to the leftover that seems to have a problem. The 16" pours should be good, just need time to cure, by water or cover with a tarp or plastic sheet. The mold can be removed the day after the pour, not to wait too long, as the form of the concrete has already stabilized but is still fragile and prone to damage. The concrete will start to harden about 48 hours after the pour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your timeframe is fine. Overworking usually refers to 1) working the *finish* of concrete too long, allowing it to dry out and cure poorly on the thin top layer, or 2) adding water to "retemper" the mix, which can weaken it throughout.

MonkeyZeus is right--12 hours is a very short cure interval. Concrete is very "green" and soft at that point. When building homes we would sometimes work on basement slabs that soon, and we had to be very careful not to scuff the surface or drop tools, which can cause divots. We could drive standard wire nails through wall plates into the slab *by hand*.

Next time, wait at least two days (48 hours). Three to 5 would be better, with a little watering in the meantime. At that point you should reach 50-75% final strength, which is usually adequate for gentle handling. (Keep in mind that standard concrete at 1½" thick is *always* fragile; it has high compression resistance but fairly weak tension strength.)

Comment: Is the 48 hour wait time before removing from molds?

Comment: From any handling, really. Any jarring can crack it. The one didn't break in your hands. It broke when you tapped it, but just didn't fall apart at that time. It's little more than cookie dough until the chemical bonds develop.

Answer (score 3):

Because this question is so far out there I want to make sure future readers understand.

1. Your cure time before it is strong enough to just move around on something like plates is literally 4-5 days at least.
2. As a lifter and former weightlifting coach I commend you for the DIY.   But for your sake and anyone reading this...   Creating your own concrete plates to seriously use has to be one of the dumbest and riskiest ideas I have ever heard.   Concrete cracks.   Concrete cracks faster when there is hole in the middle of it.   It is very likely that this will do fine for X amount of time.   For your sake I hope you are not benching as a weight cracking and falling off could mean death.   If you are squatting it, you might go to the ER.   If you are overhead pressing... well lots of things could happen, most not good.

Just helping run a gym and getting leftover plates from the 70s (metal)... a few broke, thank god during things like deadlifts or hang cleans.   We threw these out plus any like them.   Making concrete plates and using them to lift is akin to blindly rewiring your house.

Comment: Making concrete plates is a popular DIY thing lately. You can even buy molds for them.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - I get it.   But lots of popular things are dumb.   Also if they don't even break the weight of the plates are so important.   Those same 70s plates we had the 45s were actually 44.2s.   And everyone knew.   I had some guys try to find them and use them to bench for the mental boost.   Anyway if this is a craft project then fine.   If this is for serious lifting (safety) then it is a joke.

Comment: Yeah just to stress this answers, concrete weights will likely not survive being dropped even once.

Comment: @whatsisname - even taking one of the safest lifts to do - like deadlifting.... first with these you would never be sure that you could match the weight on each side.   But even with something where you are like... I can't get hurt if the weight breaks...   Well if I am deadlifting 400 and pull it up and a weight breaks off on one side... I might pull a trap or bicep/tri.   I would like to see where these casts are made from because it seems like a lawsuit waiting to happen.   I was surprised to see an Amazon link... seems like an alibaba idea to me.

Comment: @DMoore, where in my question - which was about over working concrete not powerlifting - did you conclude that I will be deadlifting 400 lbs, dropping weights, labeling the weight wrong for an ego boost? I appreciate the safety advice, but you're describing a scenario that doesn't apply to me.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - I wrote the answer for the community, not necessarily you.   I understand that you think its a good idea.    I want others to understand how dangerous this is.   Also I am not sure why that was your particular comment.   Out of all the lifts we do the bench press is for sure the most dangerous and it actually kills more people a year than sharks...   One of these crack when you are benching and you could be dead.   Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Per previous answers on curing time vs overworked - it needs at least 4-5 days before moving, the full 30 days to reach full strength before using.  The concrete is not over-worked and causing the concrete to fail.

Not to go into whether or not it's a good idea or not to build your own concrete weights for lifting, your description of how you build your weights is lacking in a lot in how to properly build the weights.

1. Don't use just any type of concrete.  Use a high-end concrete, i.e., High Strength Crack Resistant concrete
2. Insert a wire lath/mesh to increase the structural strength and decrease the chance of the weight from breaking apart
3. Add fiberglass fiber to the mix
4. Find a way to shake/vibrate the mode to remove air bubbles
5. Use a tool with a curve to round the top edge, which will help to reduce or prevent chipping on the outside edge
6. Use proper drying techniques, discussed in other answers
7. Spray with one of the various coating products to minimize chippings, like flex-rubber or truck bed liners spray/coating.

Watch some of the various YouTube videos on how to do this to get an idea of the whole process.

Comment: Thanks for the bullet list. I skipped some detail, because I was mostly concerned if I had over worked the mix. Yes, I did add in wire mesh for reinforcement, and also after 28 days of cure I plan to coat them with truck bed liner. I didn't power vibrate the molds, but tapped and shook the sides. I watched loads of YouTube videos. The funny things is _all_ of them remove, paint, and use the weights to demo _much too soon_ by the advice here.

Comment: I wish I knew the 4-5 day wait sooner. But I only moved them once, very gently, to put them in a tub of water to cure for a week. After that will be another 3 weeks to dry and cure before coating. ...I used the all purpose Quikrete concrete mix 4000 PSI rated.

Comment: You are probably ok with the larger concrete weights based on your new information.  The smaller weight would be prone to failure, because normal concrete has to be a minimum of 2", plus you didn't allow enough time to cure before removing from your DIY mold.  For you main weights, I would use the high strength, with fibre, or the ones specified as crack-resistance. On the video's, you really don't know the cure time the authors used.